# get request data chunk (body) with mitmproxy

Tags: mitmproxy

I recently use [mitmproxy](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy) and I would like to intercept request having a body, like the [node-http-mitm-proxy](https://github.com/joeferner/node-http-mitm-proxy#proxy_onRequestData) does (using the two events proxy.onRequestData(fn) and proxy.onRequestEnd(fn)).

Would it be possible with the mitmproxy to intercept the requests data chunk (the body) and eventually to have an event fired when request data (the body) is sent ?

I see that there is the possibility of intercepting the requests, but I do not see how we can intercept each request data chunk forming the body.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Mitmproxy is written in Python so the general way it works is a bit different. Instead of events there are addons and certain methods of that addon(-class) called. Check out the example addons of Mitmproxy: https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/addons-examples/

Comment: More specifically, https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/addons-examples/#http-stream-modify has an example on how you can view message data by chunk. That being said, I would strongly recommend to just work with the full buffered content where possible. It's much easier.